# Yii2 eager loading with subquery instead of array with id's

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, database-performance, eager-loading

For a big application I am using the following query to get all projects with relations:

```
  $project_query = Project::find()->With(['category', 'deliveryTickets', 'garbagePerProjects', 'hourLogs',
        'materialPerProjects', 'employeePerProjects', 'contact', 'invoices'])
        ->where(['project.organization_id' => $this->organization_id]);
```

which generates the following query, for example :

```
SELECT * FROM `delivery_ticket` WHERE `project_id` IN (124, 137, 147, 148, 149, 219, 222, 241, 1263, 1324, 1325, 1333, 1378, 1423, 1499, 1627, 1687, 1688, 1689, 1690, 1705, 1706, 1962, 2047, 2643, 2774, 2876, 2912, 3005, 3287, 3334, 4251, 4570, 4758, 4963, 5644, 6168, 6605, 6639, 6991, 7000, 7003, 7098, 7530, 7531, 7733, 7734, 7823, 7927, 8452, 8752, 8868, 8903, 8914, 8916, 8917, 8921, 8923, 8931, 8947, 8948, 8949, 8952, 8969, 9042, 9134, 9136, 9137, 9280, 9671, 10262, 10272, 10712, 10730, 11436, 11459, 11520, 11641, 11774, 11776, 12028, 12178, 12323, 12831, 12884, 13050, 13478, 13479, 13595, 13651, 13716, 13946, 14431, 14447, 14523, 15303, 15343, 16269, 16270, 16491, 16513, 17950, 17951)
```

Mysql explain shows that it is using range instead of eq_ref

therefor my page takes 3 seconds to load.

How can turn this query in a subquery ?

Comment: Does the same happen when you use `joinWith` instead of `with`?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 0):

`range` is ambiguous in this situation.  To investigate further, provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and perform these steps:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE "Handler%";
```

and look at the largest number that comes out.  Possible cases:

- Same as number of rows in the table -- You need `INDEX(project_id)`.
- Same as number of rows in output (103?) -- Then it did the optimal, namely leapfrog through the table, not do some big "range" scan like it implied.  As for "3 seconds" -- that will take some more head scratching.
- Some other number -- What version are you running?  (This may take more investigation.)  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE delivery_ticket`.